# Sort order for orchard query with filter for multiple content types

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have an orchard query filtering on content types BlogPost and Page. As sort criteria, I added "Ordered by Modification date, descending".

I expected the result list to be sorted independently of the content type, but first all pages are sorted and then all blogposts.

How can I achieve that sorting is done independantly from content type?

Comment: Sounds like a bug that should be filed on the issue tracker.

Comment: Thank you @Betrand   Done, see https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/19608